# tf.accuracy is all over the place for binary classification in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

Beginner here. I'm using tensorflow for a binary classification problem and my tf.accuracy is all over the place. It should be at a minimum 0.5 for random guessing but somehow I've managed to get 0.000 or 1.000 (and I'm positive that's not because of the supreme quality of my estimator) Here is my model function:

```
def my_model(features, labels, mode, params):

    net = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params['feature_columns'])
    for units in params['hidden_units']:
        net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=units, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)

    #output layer
    sigmoid_activations = tf.layers.dense(net, params['n_classes'], activation=tf.sigmoid)

    # Compute predictions.
    predicted_classes = tf.round(sigmoid_activations)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        predictions = {
            'class_ids': predicted_classes[:, tf.newaxis],
            'probabilities': sigmoid_activations,
        }
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)

    # Compute loss.
    loss = tf.losses.log_loss(labels, sigmoid_activations)

    # Compute evaluation metrics.
    accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels,
                                   predictions=predicted_classes,
                                   name='acc_op')
    metrics = {'accuracy': accuracy}
    tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy[1])

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
            mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)

    # Create training op.
    assert mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN

    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```

The following configuration gives an accuracy of ~=0.5 after the first epoch (there may be no signal in my data, but that's a different issue)

```
HIDDEN_UNITS=[10]
LEARNING_RATE=0.1
BATCH_SIZE=10
EPOCHS=3
```

Playing around with hyperparameters and changing the hidden units to

```
HIDDEN_UNITS=[128,64,32]
```

gives accuracy of 0.000 which makes no sense, because even random guessing should score around 0.5. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:
Turns out my test set was shuffled poorly and only had positive samples in it. For some reason (different issue) my model always predicts 1 so I got a perfect 1.0 accuracy with a terrible model.